# Change XML encoding in LabVIEW

Tags: xml, utf-16, labview

I'm trying to edit an xml file in labVIEW for use by a .NET assembly later on in the program, however, when labview saves the file it changes the encoding. This prevents the .NET assembly from being able to open the file, since it needs to be in UTF-16 or UCS-2.

Is there a way to change the encoding in labview? I can do it manually in notepad++ but obviously that wont't work when I'm actually trying to use the program. I've tried using the labview "write to xml file.vi" which allows you to specify an encoding, but it just erases most of the file.
I'm sorry if I'm being a bit vague here.

I've included a link to a drive folder with 3 xml files, which should be almost the same (at least they are when view in notepad++, not so much in drive), however the one called "working" can be loaded into my .NET assembly and  the one called "postLabviewEdit" cannot. Notice that both have the same encoding declaration (UTF-16). If I take the one that isn't working (postLabviewEdit) and open it in notepad++ and click encoding>Encode in UCS-2 Little Endian and save it it starts working again (I included this one as well).

[image]

[XML files before and after running through the program](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B8FWPOKsn2tXYXc1MXpjMU1CaGs&usp=sharing)

Comment: If you want photos, [edit] the question to include links to them.  Someone will then edit the question to have them directly in the question.

Comment: There are multiple ways to edit XML in LabVIEW. Are you using the property nodes/invoke nodes of standard library Document object? Or EasyXML? Or LabXML? Or something else?

Comment: The way to change XML encoding depends on the library you are using to handle XML file

Comment: Mikhail, I'm using property nodes

Comment: XML Document has a property: encoding

Comment: Just tried that, it changes the encoding data in the header of the xml file, but my .NET assembly still won't open it.

Comment: It only ever works if I click on "Encoding" in notepad++ and change it to UCS-2, and at the same time it has to say "encoding="UTF-16"" in the header. If I don't set it to UCS-2 in notepad++ it doesn't work.

Comment: Please, make an effort to construct the minimal reproducible example. Provide the input and output file. And see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your files are UTF-16; but  `Working.xml` have BOM  and `postLabviewEdit.xml` has not (the inicial pair of bytes (377 376=UTF16-LE)).

```
$ od -c postLabviewEditEncodedInNotepad.xml | head -1
0000000 377 376   <  \0   ?  \0   x  \0   m  \0   l  \0      \0   v  \0
$ od -c postLabviewEdit.xml| head -1
0000000   <  \0   ?  \0   x  \0   m  \0   l  \0      \0   v  \0   e  \0
$ od -c Working.xml| head -1
0000000 377 376   <  \0   ?  \0   x  \0   m  \0   l  \0      \0   v  \0
localhost:Download$
```

Apparently .NET needs BOM?

Comment: how can I get the file to have BOM in labview?

Comment: You're right this is definitely the problem, I've been trying to figure out how to do this in labview but I can't get it to work. This is the most useful info I could find http://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/Generate-and-Write-unicode-characters-to-file/td-p/3045009

Answer (score 3):

Ok So it looks like the problem was that LabVIEW was removing the BOM, as pointed out by JJoao. [I created this VI to rewrite the file with the the BOM added to the beginning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOwqA.jpg). Once I run the file through this it looks like the .NET assembly will accept it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I am glad you could find a solution!

Answer (score 2):

The code provided has the following problem: you change the element of the XML file while saving it - race condition. Edit it like that:
[image]

Comment: Thankyou, that's makes my code better but unfortunately I still have the encoding problem. I edited my post to include the xml files.

Comment: It looks like one of the problems is that the BOM is missing, (see my answer, or in fact my comment). Is there an easy way to add a 0xFFFE in the beginning of output?

Comment: what do you mean?  add 0xFFFE to the beginning of the file?